# Application.LoadfromText...load from string instead?

Tags: string, object, ms-access, import, vba

I was wondering if it is possible to use the code saved in the .txt file using the application.savetotext and save the code in a table, then use the application.loadfromtext to to build the object from a string rather that a .txt file

Does that make any sense? Basically I'm wanting to store all the object codes in a table on separate rows and allow users to select the relevant row and build the object without having to import the .txt file

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. You would have to write the field content to a (temp) file, then use *LoadFromText* to read in the object.

But it doesn't make much sense, and I think you are on a wrong track. You could just as well have the objects ready-made in application.

Comment: Basically we have a linked table to all their databases...rather than sending them .txt files or new front ends...I could simply add the code to the linked table and they can run it which will build the object...specifically forms, this method will be used to replace forms that they already have in their database..... It's basically another way of updating their database without having to send them any files to import...I know it's sounds strange and impractical but it's what I'm striving for

Comment: Currently what I have in place is some code that downloads the txt file from a linked table which has an attachment field to their desktop using application.savetotext and re-imports it back using the application.loadfromtext and finally deletes the .txt off their desktop

Comment: Have you looked at `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` for that purpose, @Max?  You wouldn't need to bother with a text file; just import the form object.

Comment: Hi hansup would that require a  download \ import a file? Which ideally I'm trying to avoid

Comment: I presumed the clients all have access to a central database where you stored the text output from `Application.SaveAsText`.  If a form exists in that database as an actual form *object*, they can import it into their local database by using `DoCmd.TransferDatabase`

Comment: @HansUp is right. Just save the objects in the database that hosts the table presently linked. Then import the objects from this as needed.

Comment: Ahh I see what your saying... This won't resolve the issue as they are linked to SharePoint lists so docmd.transferdatabase wouldn't work as there will be no other database they will be linked too....I was looking to save the code in a sharepointlist then they can run the code within their database to create an object without importing \ exporting or transfer database...I'm guessing this is getting little too ambitious

Comment: Oh, that changes the picture. But if you have SharePoint, I guess you could have a workspace to share the saved objects for read-only access?